# Perform batch write in DynamoDB in Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I want to write items to DynamoDB using AWS Lambda written in Java. I use the following code to write to DynamoDB one record at a time:

```
public void writeToDynamoDB() {
   AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDyanmoDBClientBuilder.defaultClient();
   Map<String, AttributeValue> itemValues = new HashMap<>();
   itemValues.put("partitionKey", new AttributeValue("123"));
   client.putItem("DynamoDBTable", itemValues);    
}
```

But it turns out that I need to write the records in batches. How can I do it. Is there any modification I can make to this code?

Comment: You can see the example in aws documents.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/batch-operation-document-api-java.html

Comment: Refer to the AWS Java V2 Dev Guide as i specified below for the latest code examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to perform AWS tasks with Java, check the Java Developer V2 Dev Guide located here.

[Developer guide - AWS SDK for Java 2.x](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html)

The Amazon Java SDK team recommends moving to V2.

**Amazon recommends using AWS SDK for Java 2.x, which is a major rewrite of the 1.11.x code base built on top of Java 8+. Java SDK 2.x has improved consistency, ease of use, and strongly enforced immutability. It also has support for non-blocking I/O and the ability to plug in a different HTTP implementation at run time.**

Now to perform the task that you want, use the DynamoDB API V2 and the Enhanced Client. You can [find information here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-dynamodb-enhanced.html).

See this example that demonstrates how to insert many items into an Amazon DynamoDB table by using the enhanced client.

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/dynamodb/src/main/java/com/example/dynamodb/enhanced/EnhancedBatchWriteItems.java

You can use the Java Lambda runtime API and the DynamoDB API to create a Lambda function to meet your requirements.

Comment: github link is broken.

Comment: Fixed it - the Enhanced Client examples where moved to a sub package.